# add a list of ints to a list of lists of ints

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I am trying the mock test of leetCode..

```
Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.
```

can someone pelase advice where I am going wrong...flagging

```
Line 8: Char 30: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<int, int>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' (in Solution.cs)
Line 12: Char 16: error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.Generic.IList<int>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (in Solution.cs)

public class Solution {
    public IList<IList<int>> ThreeSum(int[] nums) {

        List<List<int>> myList = new List<List<int>>();

        foreach(var i in nums)
        {
        List<int> triplets = nums.GroupBy(x => x).Where(y => y.Count() >= 3).ToList();
            myList.Add(triplets);
        }

        return myList;
    }
}
```

SO ThreeSum is an interface of a list of  lists.
So I am creating my return object myList
Iterating through each item in nums
creating an List triplet, obtaining the values, 
and adding them to myList.
I know the issue is because of the list of int lists, and I am adding a list to this.
So should triplets be an list of int lists.
I guess then the Q is how do I populate an list of int lists, with a single list??

Comment: Is your problem about algorithm correctness or c# syntax ? Or both ?

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because the List inside the for loop is not the same type that the expression is returning. The GroupBy is returning `List<System.Linq.IGrouping<int, int>>`, so this could be solved by changing either the expression to return a list of ints, or changing the type to match the returned value (`List<System.Linq.IGrouping<int, int>>`). I would think changing the expression would work better looking at what you are doing with the value after. 
The second error is because your method return type is different from the type you are returning. Your declaration suggests you will return `IList<IList<int>>` however the myList object is `List<List<int>>`. These need to match, so either change the method declaration or the myList object type, so they match. I am guessing your declaration is probably correct so I would change the myList object to match.